# URL for images folder on Multisite

Tags: multisite, htaccess, constants

I am developing a theme locally on a local multisite installation and trying to change the default gravitar with the following function:

```
function custom_gravitar ($avatar_defaults) {
  $myavatar = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/img/gravitar.gif';
  $avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "Custom gravitar";
  return $avatar_defaults;
}

add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'custom_gravitar' );
```

The path that is output is `http://i0.wp.com/localhost/my-site-folder/wp-content/themes/my-theme/img/gravitar.gif`

but my local url is `http://localhost/my-site-folder/`

I tried defining the `WP_CONTENT_URL`constant but it doesn't seem to have any impact.

I have also tried `$myavatar = get_site_url() . '/img/gravitar.gif';` and various other functions but all of them seem to include the prefix `i0.wp.com/`
I have used the suggested htaccess change to set up a MultiSite so I don't see where this is coming from.

How can I get the correct path to my images folder?